# AAC - How to avoid reference to activity in viewmodel

Tags: android, reference, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, fusedlocationproviderclient

The `FusedLocationProviderClient` that I'm using to get location information needs a reference to an activity or context. When I try to instantiate my `UserLocationService` - which implements `FusedLocationProviderClient` - inside a viewmodel, i have to pass a reference to an activity.

```
class UserLocationService {
public val locationUpdates: MutableLiveData<Location> = MutableLiveData()
private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
constructor(activity: Activity) {
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
...
```

I don't want to pass any reference to the viewmodel. What is the right approach in this case? I could use the `UserLocationService` directly in the fragment but my understanding is, that the viewmodel should do the instantiation und initialization.

Comment: There is [a version of `getFusedLocationProviderClient()` that takes an ordinary `Context`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html#getFusedLocationProviderClient(android.content.Context)), if you are willing to handle error cases via notifications.

Comment: But how can get the context inside `UserLocationService`?

Comment: I do not know what that is, from an architecture standpoint. If it is a repository or some other singleton, you can provide it the `Application` singleton when you create it (e.g., via dependency inversion). If it is just a utility class that is being used by the viewmodel, as the one answer indicates, use `AndroidViewModel` as the base class for your viewmodel. Then, you have access to `getApplication()` to get the `Application` singleton.

Comment: This is just a respository class. I've implemented the `AndroidViewModel` class from `androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel`but  `getApplication()`needs also an activity as reference like `getApplication<activity: Activity>()`

Comment: "but getApplication() needs also an activity as reference" -- no, it does not. It returns `T` where `T` extends from `Application`. [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.5/Bookmarker) demonstrates the use of `AndroidViewModel`, as does [this project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.5/ContentEditor), [this project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.5/DiceLight), and [this project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/blob/v0.5/Weather).

Comment: Oh no my mistake. :'-/ `UserLocationService` expects activity. This should context ofcourse. Thanks(!) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel).

Edit:

So what you can do is have the view model class.

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val context = application.applicationContext

}
```

And then use the context for what you need.

To initialize the view model you can do something like this in your activity.

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```

And then use it after the `onCreate()`

Comment: I there an example of how to use it? This class needs a reference to application context in the constructor.